# Gstreamer 1.18 how to access GPU data when hardware decoding

Tags: python, gstreamer, python-gstreamer

Hi im currently running into trouble creating a custom python plugin in gstreamer 1.18. I am struggling to access the gpu memory from a buffer sent from a nvida hardware decoding element (`nvh264dec`).

Here is a gst-launch pipeline showing what i am doing:

`gst-launch-1.0 -v filesrc location=VIDEO ! qtdemux ! h264parse ! nvh264dec ! <custom-element> ! fakesink`

Within `<custom-element>` i wish to access the gpu data from within the buffer sent from the `nvh264dec` . But currently, after much experimentation, i have been unable to access the gpu data. Rather when i try to access the data i seem to just get a buffer located on host. Im assuming this is due to the functioning of the buffers outputted from the `nvh264dec` element, i.e that the data is sent to host "as needed". I believe my current problem is that when i try and access the buffer data from within the chain function in my `<custom-element` it for some reason is a buffer with data on the host. My question is then, how from within the chain function of my custom element do i access the gpu data of the buffer.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: perhaps add a raw video element that will then be piped to the custom one?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I've tried something like that and it doesn't seem to be something with the caps, rather it seems to be a problem in the way I access the buffer.